# Getting error related with bean creation while run Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am learning spring boot with JPA and i have a problem when launch my app. Could somebody help me to solve this issue? Error is -

```
Description: Field userRepo in com.example.demo.controller.DemoController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repo.UserRepo' that could not be found. The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true) 
Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repo.UserRepo' in your configuration.
```

**Controller**

```
public class DemoController {
private static final String CLASS_NAME = DemoController.class.getName();
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@Autowired
private UserServiceImpl userService;

  @PostMapping(value = "/hello", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") 
  public String createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
       long count = userRepo.count();
      return "Done"; 
  }
}
```

**repository**

```
@Repository

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {    
}
```

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

**Project structure**

[image]

I annotated repository with @Repository and using @Autowired on controller. Where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of unnecessary annotations that are not required.

As per documentation -

**We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes.**

I doubt that component scan is unable to scan your **UserRepo** class.

Remove all the unnecessary annotations.

```
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Hi Ashutosh,  i have edited my question and added package structure also .

Comment: Could you please remove all the           
 @ComponentScan("com.example.demo*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})                            As for as i see they are not required.

Comment: Make sure to annotate Controller with @RestController.

Comment: I removed all as you suggest, and its working fine now. Thanks! But could you please explain why after removing all annotations from the application class its working ?

Answer (score 1):

You added quite a lot `annotations` which aren't really needed.

Make the following changes

```
     DemoController.java -> Add `@Controller or @RestController` annotation
     Application.java --> Remove annotations completely

    @ComponentScan() 
    @EnableJpaRepositories()
    @EnableAutoConfiguration()
```

Let me know if it works.

Try.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation in your configuration class. This will then scan for all classes with the `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: I am using @EnableJpaRepositories , i have edited my question and added application class also .

Comment: Can you try removing the asterisks from the package names? It is not necessary and I'm not sure if that might be causing the problem as otherwise this code looks ok to me.

Comment: Is `DemoController` properly annotated with `@Controller`?